# passive question...we do not add ANY colouring to our cakes...(where does the any go?)

Tags: passive-voice

we do not add ANY artificial coloring to our cakes

- ANY artificial coloring  is not added to our cakes :( artificial
  coloring is not added to our cakes :)

I can't work out a good reason why the ANY disappears.

Comment: ***No*** *artificial colouring **is added** to our cakes.*

Comment: _Any_ is a negative polarity item, and if it is not commanded by a negative trigger (like _not_ in the first sentence), it won't work. _Not any_ is just a detachable form of _no_, as @JasonBassford suggested, but it can't be detached just anywhere.